# Python mass email sending

Tags: python, web-services, email, smtp

I am trying to make a mass texting application. The information for each person is stored in a mysql database (i.e. %phonenumber%@text.att.net). The idea is to get all the emails as a list and input it into this script. I'm not sure if I'm going about this right.

```
import sys
from smtplib import SMTP


def sendmail(toaddy, msg):              #toaddy is a list!!!!
    debuglevel = 0
    smtp = SMTP()
    smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
    smtp.connect('YOUR.MAIL.SERVER', 26)
    smtp.login('USERNAME@DOMAIN', 'PASSWORD')
    fromaddy = USERNAME@DOMAIN
    for user in toaddy                              
        smtp.sendmail(fromaddy, user, msg)
        smtp.quit()
```

Comment: So. Does it work or not? What error are you getting?

Comment: Where does PHP come into this?

Comment: `fromaddy = USERNAME@DOMAIN` is missing quotation around the string...

Comment: Test it with a list that contains your number. Then you'll know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't quit the smtp session after the first loop. Also, instead of looping over the list of addresses, the docs indicate that `sendmail` accepts a list:

```
def sendmail(toaddy, msg):  
    debuglevel = 0
    smtp = SMTP()
    smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
    smtp.connect('YOUR.MAIL.SERVER', 26)
    smtp.login('USERNAME@DOMAIN', 'PASSWORD')
    fromaddy = 'USERNAME@DOMAIN'
    smtp.sendmail(fromaddy, toaddy, msg)
    smtp.quit()
```